# create table error in mysql. 1071 error

Tags: mysql

hi all can some one plz help me,
while creating table in mysql i am getting the following error

MySQL error 1071: Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

my table definition is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE oauth_consumer (id char(36)  NOT NULL ,
  name varchar(255)  NULL ,
  date_entered datetime  NULL ,
  date_modified datetime  NULL ,
  modified_user_id char(36)  NULL ,
  created_by char(36)  NULL ,
  description text  NULL ,
  deleted bool  DEFAULT '0' NULL ,
  assigned_user_id char(36)  NULL ,
  c_key varchar(255)  NULL ,
  c_secret varchar(255)  NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  UNIQUE ckey (c_key)
);
```

Comment: Why i copy your code and run it on sqlFiddle, it worked fine. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/77276

Comment: No issues in mysql prompt also @Moiz Shaikh

Answer (score 0):

No problem in your query. May be you are running old version of MySql. Use new version. If you are using new version try to use following query to create table

```
CREATE TABLE `oauth_consumer` (
    `id` CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_entered` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `date_modified` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `modified_user_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `created_by` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NULL,
    `deleted` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `assigned_user_id` CHAR(36) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c_key` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `c_secret` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `ckey` (`c_key`)
)
COLLATE='latin1_swedish_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: @FathahRehmanP there's nothing wrong with the `CREATE` table statement, see here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/632802/1

Comment: @JW.- in my above query i used innodb engine.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your database character set is most likely set to utf8, so your 255 characters get blown up to 765 characters; though close, that's not greater than the imposed limit of 767, but it gives an idea of why you're hitting that limit nonetheless.

Regardless, it's not recommended to use such a wide key; you could calculate an md5 or sha1 of the value and use that for the unique key instead (btw, you should use the binary representation of the hash).